# Regarding usage of const in this scenario

Tags: c++11, constants

```
Header file has this.
std::string m_StrId;

Source file has this.
const std::string& getStringId() const { return  m_StrId; }
```

I am seeing these two lines of code.
What is the purpose of the second const here ?

Comment: It indicates that the `getStringId` function can only be invoked from a `const` object.

Comment: @0x5453 - Just revisiting this. What would be the purpose of the first const then ? Does it mean that what getStringId() is returning is a const string ?

Comment: Technically a reference to a const string, but yes that is essentially correct.

Comment: perfect, yes a reference . Thanks !